# Wi-Fi LED is off when Wi-Fi is on

Tags: wireless, 14.04, wifi-hardware-switch

My Wi-Fi LED on Asus UX31E only turns on after I press Fn+F2, even though Wi-Fi turns on automatically on startup. So Wi-Fi LED is off when Wi-Fi is on.

```
/sys/class/leds/ath9k-phy0/brightness
```

Shows correct values. I've tried changing it to no avail.

Note: It might have to do with having blacklisted and killed bluetooth.

```
echo 'blacklist btusb' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo 'rfkill block bluetooth' >> /etc/rc.local
```

In Grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

My device is

```
    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

How can I reverse the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why after much teasting. Eventually I realized that the led indicator for Wi-Fi is dependent on Bluetooth. Bluetooth needs to be unblocked for the led to be on.

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

This will turn the led indicator off, and vice versa. Doing the same for WLAN doesn't affect the led indicator. The issue was having bluetooth blocked on startup, which then caused WLAN and Bluetooth to have opposite status. Using the function key for Wi-Fi would flip the status of both Bluetooth and WLAN.

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

Blacklisting, but unblocking Bluetooth on startup, was a desirable solution for me. The Unity indicator for Bluetooth does not show up regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Install package kexec-tools.
Turn your Wi-Fi led off.

Open a terminal window and load the current kernel.

```
sudo kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r) --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) --reuse-cmdline
```

Execute the kernel,

```
sudo kexec -e
```

and quickly press Fn+F2.

This fixed the problem for me, but I can't guarantee that it will work for you. If it doesn't work immediately, try a few more times.

Comment: I got it to work one time, but after messing around with other stuff, it stopped working alltogether. I used rfkill to block and unblock wlan, but that doesn't affect the led. It seems only the pressing of the button affects it. One possible solution is to rfkill wlan at startup, since the led is off. However, that brings up issues because there's two identities for wlan and it seems to strike randomly when I use the function key. The most ideal thing would be to be able to turn on the led at startup (hardcode).